# Neo4j eager load ActiveRel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, neo4j, neo4jrb

I'm tryin to get specific keywords that MAY be related ONLY to specific users and the return the relationships.

```
Keyword.where(text: ['key1', 'key2'])
  .tagged_users(:u, :rel)
  .where(uid: [100, 101])
  .pluck(:rel).each_with_object({}) do |rel, obj|
      uid     = rel.to_node.uid
      keyword = rel.from_node.text
      obj[uid] ? obj[uid] << keyword : obj[uid] = [keyword]
   end
```

Assuming we have only one relationship with User 100 tagged with Keyword 'key2' the desired result is { 100 => ['key2'] }

The above code works, but for each `rel` it's performing 2 queries to the db; one for `rel.to_node` and one for `rel.from_node`.

I was hoping there is a solution to 'eager load' the `rel.from_node` and `rel.to_node` so only one query will be executed for the entire snippet.

(Another solution would be to run for each keyword and getting it's tagged users but this is also requires many queries.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add `with_associations` so we don't even need the relation object.

```
def self.uids_to_keywords(keywords, user_ids)
    Keyword.where(text: keywords).tagged_users.with_associations(:keywords)
        .where(user_id: user_ids).each_with_object({}) do |user, obj|
      obj[user.user_id] = keywords & user.keywords.map(&:text)
    end
end
```

Comment: It feels like there should be a more elegant solution. Please post it if you have one